# Read floating point numbers from file and sort to screen

Tags: python, sorting

I am attempting to read a file that contains floating point numbers that I want to then sort and print to the screen. I have been able to do this within a list contained in the program so I assumed that if I can read the file and input the data into a list, I can then sort it. The data is separated by commas so I am not sure if I should be using the CSV library.
Here is my code segment:

```
print "Program to read numbers from file and sort"
mylist=open ("numbers.txt").readlines() 
sorted (mylist)
print (mylist)
```

The program output does not seem to be sorting at all. I did try to use the .splitlines("'") but it causes an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sorted()` just returns a sorted version of a list.  To change the list in-place, use `list.sort()`:

```
print "Program to read numbers from file and sort"
mylist=open ("numbers.txt").readlines() 
mylist.sort()
print (mylist)
```

If you actually want a list of all of the floating point numbers, use `.read()` instead and give `.sort()` a key:

```
mylist = open("numbers.txt").read().split(",")
mylist.sort(key=float)
```

If you want a bunch of sublists from the file:

```
mylist = open("numbers.txt")
mylist = [sorted(line.split(","), key=float) for line in mylist]
```

Comment: When I read the numbers from a CSV file, the sort does not work properly.Here is the output:[' -3.263', ' -37.507', ' -38.797', ' -55.552\n', ' 14.354', ' 27.999', ' 40.079', ' 65.213', ' 7.581', ' 90.374', ' 99.323', '70.920']
I seem to remember that the \n indicates that there is a linefeed in the text file. I converted the data file to use a space between values instead of the , delimiter. Here is the output. ['-55.552\n', '-38.797', '-37.507', '-3.263', '7.581', '14.354', '27.999', '40.079', '65.213', '70.920', '90.374', '99.323']
That is sorted properly but the \n character is there.

Comment: @NeilPlotnick: Which one?

Comment: print "Program to read numbers form file and sort"
mylist=open ("numbers.txt").read().split(",")
mylist.sort()
print (mylist)
Is the issue with the data? I created the file using Nano.

Comment: Do this: `mylist = sorted(map(int, open("numbers.txt").read().split(",")))`

Comment: mylist = sorted(map(int, open("numbers.txt").read().split(",")))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '70.920'

Comment: I'm sorry.  It should be `float`, not `int`: `mylist = sorted(map(float, open("numbers.txt").read().split(",")))`

Comment: Works!! Thanks for the assistance!